# Chaining Retrofit and return only observer from local sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, retrofit, rx-java

I'm pretty new to RxJava and using it within Android.

In my presenter I'm trying to fetch my data named assignments with retrofit using RxJava.

The algorithm is very simple, check if there are any local assignments stored, if not fetch from remote server and then try to fetch from local again.

Currently what it does is to fetch from remote server if local sqlite returns 0 results. I would like it to return only from local sqlite, e.g how do I make it call 
`mRepository.query(new AssignmentSpecification.class)` again and return only that?

**UPDATED TO CURRENT SOLUTION**

```
restartableLatestCache(REQUEST_ASSIGNMENTS,
        () -> {

            Observable<List<Assignment>> assignmentsFromLocalDb = mRepository.query(new AssignmentSpecification())
                    .flatMap(assignments -> assignments == null || assignments.isEmpty() ?
                        Observable.zip(mRetrofit.create(AssignmentService.class)
                                            .GET(mAccessToken)
                                            .flatMap(mRepository::add),
                                    mRetrofit.create(EntityService.class)
                                            .GET(mAccessToken)
                                            .flatMap(mEntityRepository::add),
                                    mRetrofit.create(FacilityService.class)
                                            .GET(mAccessToken)
                                            .flatMap(mFacilityRepository::add),
                                    (dbAssignments, remoteEntities, remoteFacilities) -> dbAssignments)
                                    .flatMap(dbAssignments ->  mRepository.query(new AssignmentSpecification()) : Observable.just(assignments));

            return assignmentsFromLocalDb
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(mainThread());
        },
        (assignmentsFragment, response) -> assignmentsFragment.onSuccess(response),
        (assignmentsFragment, throwable) -> assignmentsFragment.onError(throwable)
    );
```

**Repository example**

```
@Override
public Observable<List<Assignment>> query(Specification specification) {
    final SqlSpecification sqlSpecification = (SqlSpecification) specification;

    final SQLiteDatabase database = mOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    final List<Assignment> assignments = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        final Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(sqlSpecification.toSqlQuery(), new String[]{});

        for (int i = 0, size = cursor.getCount(); i < size; i++) {
            cursor.moveToPosition(i);

            assignments.add(mToAssignmentMapper.map(cursor));
        }

        cursor.close();

        return Observable.just(assignments);
    } finally {
        database.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need facilities and entities?

Comment: They are not provided by assignment and contains metadata that assignment needs. This will happen only first time the app is started and no data exists yet.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming repositories looks like:

```
interface Repository {
    Observable<List<Assignment>> query(AssignmentSpecification assignmentSpecification);
    Observable<List<Assignment>> add(List<Assignment> assignments);
}
```

Than you can use this code to obtain data:

```
Observable<List<Assignment>> assigmnets = mRepository.query(new AssignmentSpecification())
        .flatMap(assignments -> assignments == null || assignments.isEmpty() ? Observable.zip(mRetrofit.create(AssignmentService.class)
                        .GET(mAccessToken)
                        .flatMap(mRepository::add),
                mRetrofit.create(EntityService.class)
                        .GET(mAccessToken)
                        .flatMap(mEntityRepository::add),
                mRetrofit.create(FacilityService.class)
                        .GET(mAccessToken)
                        .flatMap(mFacilityRepository::add),
                (apiAssignments, entities, facilities) -> apiAssignments)
                .flatMap(apiAssignments -> mRepository.query(new AssignmentSpecification())) : Observable.just(assignments));
```

Comment: Wow, that was a looooot cleaner than my solution, thanks mate!

Comment: I found a problem, dbAssignments is the result of mRepository.query(new AssignmentSpecification()). Which gives me null, I would need it to query once again AFTER mRetrofit calls are done and added to database.

How is that possible?

Comment: You need to query once again in flatMap. Answer is edited.

Comment: Seems almoste to work correctly, but the return result is now 3 null assignments.

Comment: Updated both current solution and repository

Comment: I think I have an idea. Facilities and Entities are in the same table as Assignments?

Comment: No, they are in separate tables. Assignment has a reference to both Facility and Entity.